# How can I fix a 403 Forbidden Error when running Flask on Apache in a Windows VM on AWS?

Tags: python, windows, apache, flask

Getting 403 Forbidden Error Apache Windows,
I am trying to run a flask application on Apache through a windows vm on aws, I linked Apache to flask through wsgi, and I think it is setup correctly, could someone help me out I have been stuck on this for far too long now, any help is appriciated.

I checked the error logs and I am getting a AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/wsgi_scripts/server.wsgi error

This is my config file I have included in the apache config, I am trying to get http and https to work which is why I have port 80 and 443 on
<VirtualHost *:80>
SSLEngine off
ServerName [www.example.me](http://www.example.me)
WSGIScriptAlias / C:/wsgiscripts/server.wsgi
<Directory "C:/Machine">
AllowOverride All
Require all granted


<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine on
ServerName [www.example.me](http://www.example.me)
WSGIScriptAlias / /wsgiscripts/server.wsgi
<Directory "C:/Machine">
AllowOverride All
Require all granted

I have also tried changing the directory multiple times and making sure the files are accessible through the apache server but apparently there is something I am not checking.

my wsgi file is listed below, I dont think you need to see this, but I am leaving it here just in case.

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:\Machine')
from server import app as application